# How to design dependency in Javascript application?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, requirejs

I am working on an application written in Javascript(in browser), and using requirejs to modulize the program structure.

I understand the conventional way to specify the dependency is
to fill dependent modules in the array of define/require function;

But I think there is(at least) another way to do that:
I can just pass the dependent module(or module instance) to another module as a function parameter. like below:

```
// ExampleRenderer.js
define([], // no explicit dependency
       function() {
           var context = {}; // fill in some context for rendering
           return {
               "render": function(externalRenderer) {
                   externalRenderer.render(context);
               }
           };
       });
```

Note that I did not put `externalRenderer` into the dependency array.

My question is, is there any guideline to decide whether to use explicit dependency or function parameter?

EDIT:
I think I should add my motivation here, in case of I am asking for a solution to a wrong question.
Motivation: I want to unittest some part of my program by replacing some module with mocking module. By using the explicit dependency array, I think I can not find and replace one particular module in a deep hierarchy.

Comment: you are on the right track to a well-written app. read up on Dependency Injection, or more abstractly, the concept of Inversion Of Control.

Comment: @Bergi I let the caller of `render` function(the one in module exported by example code) load the `externalRenderer`.

Comment: as written, the code has no dependencies and returns from a pure function, so of course you don't need to define any depends. you need to balance the flexibility of re-usable code like this with the specificity of the actual app logic and data. if it's a specialized app, err towards a simpler tight coupling, but if you see this becoming a suite of applications, err towards re-usability. It's essentially the diff between prefab and on-site construction; how many houses need built, how fast, and how big are the kind of questions to ask yourself.